# Drupal 8 customizing view title in module

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-views, drupal-8, titlebar

I am using the following code to change a view title to a custom title:

```
function MYMODULE_preprocess_page_title(&$variables) {
  if (some logic to check if this is the correct view)
    $variables['title] = 'Something Different!';
}
```

This works to change the title in the content area within the `<h1>` tag, but the title of the browser tab is not changed (in `<html><header><title>...</title>`).

What is the correct way to change the view title to reflect both in the page body and the browser title?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/181828/how-do-i-set-the-page-title) page should be able to help.

tl;dr You can either set the title in the `*.routing.yml` file (either statically or dynamically) or you can set the title by setting `#title` in a markup array.

Answer (score 1):

It will depends on how you build or what theme you are using, for example for change the HTML title using the default system theme it use something like this
https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/8.4.x/core/modules/system/templates/html.html.twig#L32

```
 <title>{{ head_title|safe_join(' | ') }}</title>
```

In this case you need to look what the values are for it, I would recommend to look for the value into the page preprocessor.